# MATLAB to R Conversion: Append values to an existing empty array through for loop

Tags: r, matlab

I have the below code with me. This code was written originally in MATLAB. I have two questions here:

1) What would be the corresponding command in R for the below command in MATLAB:

```
   duet(i).p = [];
```

2) In the below code I am getting all the correct 6 values for `duet$n`, but I am not getting correct values for `duet$p`. My question is how to append the values to an empty existing array `duet$p[i]` in R through the for loop iterations.

This line is not working in the below code:

```
duet$p[i] <- c(duet$p[i],j)
```

I might also have declared `duet$p[i] <- array()` incorrectly.

The values for `duet.n` and `duet.p` from MATLAB are:

```
duet.n 
    2 0 2 0 1 3

duet.p 
    [] [3,6] [] [1,3,5,6] [1,6] []
```

In R, I am getting `duet$n` values correctly, but I am not able to get the array kind of results for `duet$p`.

Any help to get the `duet$p` values would be appreciated.

```
x <- matrix(c(-1,2,4,1,7,4.2,3,0,1.2,-1.2,5.1,4,2,3.1,1.1,1,1,9,0,1,2,2,8,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),nrow=6,ncol=5,byrow=T)  
fro=1;N=6;M=2;V=3;
F <- list(f=c())
duet = list()
for (i = 1 : N){
duet$n[i] = 0
duet$p[i] = array()  ## Create an empty array
       for (j in 1 : N){
          dl = 0
          de = 0
          dm = 0
             for (k = 1 : M){
                 if (x[i,V + k] < x[j,V + k]){
                      dl = dl + 1
                 } else if (x[i,V + k] == x[j,V + k]){
                      de = de + 1
                 } else{
                      dm = dm + 1
             }
       }
    if (dl == 0 & de != M){
        duet$n[i] = duet$n[i] + 1
    } else if (dm == 0 & de != M){
        duet$p[i] = c(duet$p[i],j)
    }
}   
if (duet$n[i] == 0){
    x[i,6] = 1
    F$f = c(F$f,i)
}
}
```

Comment: "Append values to an existing empty array through for loop" 1) You should try very hard to find a vectorized alternative to the loop. 2) You should never grow an object in a loop (that's one of the slowest operations possible in any programming language) if you know or can estimate its final size. Pre-allocate and fill the data structure. Anyway, instead of a close translation of Matlab code, consider what that code is doing, rewrite it in an R-ish way and test if the R code gives identical results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to get the output you want:

```
x <- matrix(c(-1,2,4,1,7,4.2,3,0,1.2,-1.2,5.1,4,2,3.1,1.1,1,1,9,0,1,2,2,8,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),nrow=6,ncol=5,byrow=T)  
fro=1;N=6;M=2;V=3;
F <- list(f=c())
duet = list(n=rep(0,N), p=lapply(1:N, function(x)c()))
for (i in 1 : N){
  duet$n[i] = 0
  #duet$p[[i]] = c()  ## Create an empty array
  #if(i==2) browser()
  for (j in 1 : N){
    k=1:M
    dl <- sum(x[i,V + k] < x[j,V + k])
    de <- sum(x[i,V + k] == x[j,V + k])
    dm <- sum(x[i,V + k] > x[j,V + k])

    if (dl == 0 & de != M){
      duet$n[i] = duet$n[i] + 1
    } else if (dm == 0 & de != M){
      duet$p[[i]] = c(duet$p[[i]],j)
    }
  }   
  if (duet$n[i] == 0){
    #x[i,6] = 1
    F$f = c(F$f,i)
  }
}
```

What have I done?

- commented out the line `x[i,6] =1`, because there isn't an `x[i,6]`, and I'm not sure what you meant it to be. **You will need to sort this out.**
- Initialised   duet$n as a vector
- Initialised duet$p as a list of `n` empty vectors
- removed the `k` loop as conditional counting in R can be done as the sum of elements where the condition is `TRUE`.
- corrected the syntax of for loops: `=` became `in`

Comment: Thank you, that part worked perfectly. I have done the editing for x[i,6] = 1 as per my requirements. The important thing was that declaration of duet$p. Trying to learn few of the commands you used. If I understand this completely, then only I can jump to my next section of the script I have. Got to learn so much from this. :) Thank you once again!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you're trying to do `duet[i]$p` instead of what you're doing. Also you need to initialize each cell as a list

Comment: This is not an answer. At best it's a comment.